How to have BelongsToMany with multiple relations in the OctoberCMS backend?
I have models domain, domain_view and view.
In domain I have this relation
public $belongsToMany = [

        'views' => [
            \QBUT\Manager\Models\View::class,
            'table' => 'qbut_manager_domain_view',
            'pivot' => ['id', 'position', 'position_detail', 'active'],
            'pivotSortable' => 'sorting',
            'timestamps' => true
        ],
    ];

In the backend when I add a View model with ID 1 (just an example) to the a Domain model I can only add that ID 1 View once. Why is that? Why can’t I have multiple records of the same View?
Maybe I used the wrong relationship?
I tried to add the same record manually in the database and it works and I don’t see any errors. However when I delete one type all the same View types get deleted, so there’s obviously a constraint there.
I think this is not related to how the database or relationships are set but more about how the backend is set?
Still trying to figure out how and why this the default behavior?
Why does it assume I can only have one specific View model related for each Domain model?

I think i'm looking for "duplicate relationships" if that makes sense
